# Connect data (collected before user is logged in) to user account (after user logs in) - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a Django project where a quiz is taken when someone visits the website. The visitor answers all the questions and then the result is generated. But the user needs to log-in/signup to see the result.

When the user submits the quiz, data is stored in the quiz table which has a foreign key of the user model.

My question is how can I link that quiz table object to the user account when they log in or register to see the result?

"""

## quiz model

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    ques2 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=choices, default="", verbose_name = "I've always dreamed of")
    ques3 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=choices, default="", verbose_name = "I prefer to")
    ques4 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="", verbose_name = "I want to earn")
    ques9 = models.CharField(max_length=1000,  default="", blank=True, verbose_name = "How would you describe your personality?")
    ques10 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="", blank=True, verbose_name = "What are your goals?")
    result = models.ForeignKey(Moneymaker, on_delete= models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default="", related_name='result')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

"""

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use **Django Sessions** to save the data. When users log in to the site, their anonymous session is lost and a new session is created for authenticated users. If you store items in an anonymous session that you need to keep after the user logs
in, you will have to copy the old session data into the new session.

You can do this by retrieving the session data before you log in
the user using the `login()` function of the Django authentication
system and storing it in the session after that.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain with some clarification or with some example.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can use the Django session, when the user is a guest user, you can save the data using the session, and when the user login, copy the data and delete the guest user.

```
def Add_To_Cart(request, pk):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user = request.user
    try:
        """ Customer Model """
        """ you can create user or guest user in Customer Model """
        authenticate_user, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        customer = authenticate_user

        """ here you can get guest user account """
        guest_user = Customer.objects.get(user=None)

        """ i have two models for my E-commerce website(OrderPost|Order) """

        """ here you can copy and create OrderPost objects from guest_user """
        guest_orderitems = OrderPost.objects.get(user=guest_user, ordered=False)
        order_item, created = OrderPost.objects.get_or_create(
            user=customer,
            item= guest_orderitems.item,
            qunatity= guest_orderitems.qunatity,
            ordered=False
        )
        guest_user.delete()
    except:
        authenticate_user, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        customer = authenticate_user 

else:
    """ When a guest user visits your website, 
        the guest user will be created without username and only with session_key """
    try:
        session_key = request.COOKIES['sessionid']
    except:
        return '0'
    customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(session_key=session_key)
```